# ¿Como puedo producir un gráfico con dos variables en el eje Y con escalas distintas con ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Quiero graficar dos series de variables en el eje Y. Cada una tiene una escala diferente, por lo que es necesario generar un eje Y auxiliar para una de las series.
La gráfica anexa es una aproximación de lo que busco.
El eje X se llama SP.

Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respuesta rápida: lamentablemente no puedes,`ggplot2` no contempla esto y lo dice  el propio autor de este paquete [Hadley Wickham](http://hadley.nz/) ([Ver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3101876/6836377)). Voy a intentar tradducir su respuesta lo mejor posible:

> No es posible en ggplot2 porque creo que las gráficas con escalas "y"
>   separadas (no las escalas "y" que son transformaciones de la otra)
>   son fundamentalmente defectuosas. Algunos problemas:
>
> - No son invertibles: dado un punto en el espacio de la gráfica, no se    puede mapear de manera univoca un punto en el espacio de datos.
> - Son relativamente difíciles de leer correctamente en comparación con     otras opciones. Ver [Un estudio sobre gráficos de datos a
>     doble escala](https://www.lri.fr/~isenberg/publications/papers/Isenberg_2011_ASO.pdf)    de Petra Isenberg, Anastasia Bezerianos, Pierre
>     Dragicevic y       Jean-Daniel Fekete para más detalles.
> - Son fácilmente manipulables para engañar: no hay una forma única de        especificar las escalas relativas de los ejes, dejándolos abiertos a
>     la manipulación. Dos ejemplos del blog de Junkcharts: [uno](http://junkcharts.typepad.com/junk_charts/2006/06/illusion_of_suc.html),
>     [dos](http://junkcharts.typepad.com/junk_charts/2006/05/the_crossover_l.html)
> - Son arbitrarias: ¿por qué tener sólo 2 escalas, y no 3, 4 o 10?
>
> También puede que quieras leer la larga discusión de Stephen Few sobre
>   el tema [Los ejes de doble escala en los gráficos ¿Son alguna vez la
>   mejor solución?](http://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/visual_business_intelligence/dual-scaled_axes.pdf).